# Can't resolve './src' when defining custom entry point, after migrating to webpack v5 from v4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-5

I have a isomorphic app and has two entry points ./src/client.js and ./src/server.js defined in respective config but getting the error can't resolve './src'

Solutions tried:

- Using absolute path
- using the extensions key in resolve.

How to debug it?

Comment: Show the `webpack.config.js` and your folder structure

Comment: @LinDu I fixed it,I was using import and export syntax.I changed it to require and module.exports syntax and it got fixed.Thanks for the response.